# I want to list of all languages in qtranslate wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, qtranslate

I want to get list of all available languages in array in qtranslate wordpress plugin. Is there any function qtranslate wordpress plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to get but, within qTranslate plugin, there is a capability to check all available Languages.

Moreover, you can define default language, add or remove languages too.

**Administration Screen -> Settings ->Language**